# Error in Hadoop 2.2 while starting in windows

Tags: hadoop, cygwin

I am trying to install hadoop on windows7.i have installed cygwin, when i do ./start-dfs.sh i am getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-kalai-namenode kalai-PC.out
localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-kalai-datanode-kalai-PC.out
localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf
```

Can anyone let me know what i'm doing here wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The above issue gets cleared when I used Command Prompt with admin privileges for Formatting namenode and starting services.

1. Removed the C:\tmp and C:\data directories manually
2. Open a cmd.exe with 'Run as Administrator"
3. Format the namenode and start the services.